# Pressure and velocity change at window

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

When the pressure and velocity of atmosphere(out side of room) are Pa and Va, how do pressure and velocity of wind change at window?
Set the window size 'A'. Please explain this. Thank you.

Comment: If the wind is blowing perpendicular to the window, what do you think the component of the wind velocity is at the window, in the direction perpendicular to the window?

Comment: Did you try applying Bernoulli's equation?